# when condition is true then inner join comes in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do inner join when some condition is true

```
case  
when (select dbo.fnGetProduct_config('CATEGORY_NAME','',''))='XYZ'  
then inner join product_master t12 on t12.id=t1.product_id  
END
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a conditional to decide whether or not to join (except with dynamic sql), but you can add the predicate to the join....

```
...
from table1
inner join product_master t12 on t12.id=t1.product_id and dbo.fnGetProduct_config('CATEGORY_NAME','',''))='XYZ'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
 ON (fn(T1.Blahblah)==1 AND /*other conditions*/)
```